# Wordpress plugin not showing up on development subdomain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, plugins

Good day!

I have a wordpress plugin that I am currently continuing development on for a 3rd party. the plugin works amazingly in the main website but as soon as i want to start development and testing within a subdomain invironment it throws a 404. so Somesite.com/schools works, but development.somesite.com/schools throws a 404

I added the code of a router within the plugin. /schools should show the page but doesn't and i can't seem the find the url written anywhere within the plugin.

````
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import FormPage from './components/FormPage';

const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/school/:loginCode" component={FormPage}/>
      <Route exact path="/enter-school-info" component={FormPage}/>
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
);

render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#stp-frontend-page-wrapper'),
);```
````

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the basname such as this. I'm not sure. So please give it a try <HashRouter basename="/schools"/>

Comment: this sadly didn't change anything @ozgur

Comment: I submitted an answer below that may work for you. It will simply tell your Apache server to redirect requests to index.html where your react app lives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was that someone deleted the page with the shortcode from the development domain. so /schools didn't technically exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this code in a `.htaccess` file and upload it to your plugin folder where your **index.html** is in

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```